# Is there a good reason why EF is not able to determine the order of a composite key by simply following the order the marked fields were declared?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

From MSDN's [Code First Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583#Composite):

> When you have composite keys, Entity Framework requires you to define an order of the key properties. You can do this using the Column annotation to specify an order.

I am wondering why Microsoft did not make EF capable of determining the composite key order, **whenever not explicitly declared** - simply based on the order the fields marked with `[Key]` are declared ?

Is there a good reason behind the absence of this functionality ?

It can be annoying to declare the order of several composite keys.

Comment: It would be *more* annoying if changing the order of the fields caused your data access code to fail, or triggered a migration. Changing the field order isn't even considered a refactoring.

Comment: BTW, having a lot of composite keys is a DB design smell, even for many-to-many tables. Editing such tables using EF is very frustrating because there is no way to separate a delete/create from an update without a unique key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> based on the order the fields marked with `[Key]` are declared ?

I do not think that the CLI guarantees – unless one uses the [`StructLayoutAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) the order in memory, or returned by reflection APIs – matches the order in the source code.

Answer (score 3):

I think the primary reason is fragility of the approach.

Since the `[Key]` columns can come from different classes in your inheritance hierarchy, rules would need to be defined to avoid ambiguity. For example, framework designers would need to specify that components of a composite key inherited from a base class have precedence over components defined in a derived class:

```
class BaseEntity {
    [Key]
    public int KeyPartBase {get;set;}
}
class DerivedEntity : BaseEntity {
    [Key]
    public int KeyPartDerived {get;set;}
}
```

This would lead to a problem if you decide to flatten your hierarchy. Let's say someone who was refactoring your code wasn't careful enough, and moved `KeyPartBase` below `KeyPartDerived`:

```
class DerivedEntity  {
    [Key]
    public int KeyPartDerived {get;set;}
    [Key]
    public int KeyPartBase {get;set;}
}
```

This change has no effect on the code part, but it would break the order of key parts, leading to a subtle and extremely hard to find bug.

Comment: I honestly think the conclusion should not be "give this approach up", rather make changes in model types warn about order changes. Based on the 2 answers I think Richard's is more of a reason as why not to do this - than yours.